# Eclipse Plugin Development : How to get event on eclipse plugin installation / updation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a custom eclipse plugin.
My requirement is to get an event as the eclipse plugin install or update completes.

It can be either before restart of eclipse or after restart of eclipse.

In case of plugin install I require an event because as plugin installed successfully I want to show a customized message of successful installation.

In case of plugin update I require an event to make some changes in some of my work space files.

Please suggest me how Can I come to know that install / update completed and from where I can call my procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get event of plugin installation, because installation requires restart for Eclipse registry update to take effect.

For the second part (after plugin udate), you may keep current version in some workspace file (e.g. preferences),
then on plugin start check if current plugin version is bigger than version in workspace, then take some actions.